# Get all AppRole assignments in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I use PowerShell command `New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment` to assign AppRoles to Users or Groups.

How can I get a list of current `AppRole -> User` assignments for my app? Or otherwise list all Users and Groups of my App in **PowerShell** or via **AzureAD Graph API**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this command works:

`Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId [service principal object ID]`

It lists all users and groups that are assigned an AppRole from the app represented by the service principal.

Comment: Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment is only available in Az 2.0, any idea how to do this in Az 9.6?

Comment: @WouldBeNerd Get-AzRoleAssignment.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-powershell#list-role-assignments-for-a-managed-identity

Comment: @Coden00b thanks for the pointer, I haven't been able to figure out how to get assigned app roles for a particular App registration for one user. When i use 
`Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $global:modify_user_id ` I get an array of 2 back. It shows me they are own of a Resource Group and also Owner of the app Registration.

Comment: @WouldBeNerd to get role assignments for a resource, for a particular user you could use Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/..." -SignInName john_doe.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 2):

Using Azure AD Graph API:

To list all app roles a user is assigned:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

To list all app roles a group is assigned:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/groups/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

To do the reverse, and list all users or groups assigned to an app:

```
 https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.6
```

Alternative option: In the new Azure portal, under "Enterprise applications" > (your app) > "Users and groups", you'll see the list of users who are assigned to the application, as well as the app role they are assigned to. After testing, you could do the equivalent thing using a Microsoft Graph API request :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036/appRoleAssignments
```

You could get the service principal under "Enterprise applications" > (your app) > Properties> Object ID